# Table has no columns - Google Charts - PHP AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-visualization

I started to learn how to use Google Charts today and I'm a bit stuck.

I have dynamic data (changes about 3-4 times a day) to pump into the chart (Pie Chart). I'm using AJAX as the data source and PHP as my backend.. I tried to do it this way but to no avail:

AJAX:

```
<?php
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/galaxy-connect.php';

$database = new Connection();
$database = $database->Connect();
$statement = $database->Prepare(" SELECT COUNT(Membership_Level_Name) AS MemTotal, Membership_Level_Name
FROM membership AS M
LEFT JOIN membership_levels AS L
ON M.`Membership_Level_Id` = L.`Membership_Level_Id`
LEFT JOIN membership_status AS S
ON M.`MembershipStatusId` = S.MembershipStatusId
WHERE M.`MembershipStatusId` = 1
GROUP BY L.`Membership_Level_Name`
ORDER BY L.`Membership_Level_Id` ");

$statement->execute();
$MembershipTotals = $statement->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

if (!empty($MembershipTotals)) {
    foreach ($MembershipTotals as $MembershipTotal) {
        $data[] = array(
            "cols" => array("id"=>"Membership_Level_Name", "label"=>"Membership Level", "type"=>"varchar"),
                 array("id"=>"MemTotal", "label"=>"Total", "pattern"=>"", "type"=>"number"),
            "rows" => array($MembershipTotal['Membership_Level_Name'], $MembershipTotal['MemTotal'])
        );
    }
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

so thats my ajax, and it produces:

(ok wont let me post an image but heres the results)

```
[{"cols":{"id":"Membership_Level_Name","label":"Membership Level","type":"varchar"},"0":{"id":"MemTotal","label":"Total","pattern":"","type":"number"},"rows":["Start Up","24"]},{"cols":{"id":"Membership_Level_Name","label":"Membership Level","type":"varchar"},"0":{"id":"MemTotal","label":"Total","pattern":"","type":"number"},"rows":["Member","131"]},{"cols":{"id":"Membership_Level_Name","label":"Membership Level","type":"varchar"},"0":{"id":"MemTotal","label":"Total","pattern":"","type":"number"},"rows":["Member Plus","170"]},{"cols":{"id":"Membership_Level_Name","label":"Membership Level","type":"varchar"},"0":{"id":"MemTotal","label":"Total","pattern":"","type":"number"},"rows":["Premier Member","31"]},{"cols":{"id":"Membership_Level_Name","label":"Membership Level","type":"varchar"},"0":{"id":"MemTotal","label":"Total","pattern":"","type":"number"},"rows":["Bronze","97"]},{"cols":{"id":"Membership_Level_Name","label":"Membership Level","type":"varchar"},"0":{"id":"MemTotal","label":"Total","pattern":"","type":"number"},"rows":["Silver","145"]},{"cols":{"id":"Membership_Level_Name","label":"Membership Level","type":"varchar"},"0":{"id":"MemTotal","label":"Total","pattern":"","type":"number"},"rows":["Gold","188"]},{"cols":{"id":"Membership_Level_Name","label":"Membership Level","type":"varchar"},"0":{"id":"MemTotal","label":"Total","pattern":"","type":"number"},"rows":["Affiliate","3"]},{"cols":{"id":"Membership_Level_Name","label":"Membership Level","type":"varchar"},"0":{"id":"MemTotal","label":"Total","pattern":"","type":"number"},"rows":["Charity\/Education","4"]}]
```

So the next step is to call that data, I took the code from Google Charts "Connecting to a database" (or something like that) page:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "/ajax/charts/membershiptotals.php",
          dataType:"json",
          async: false
          }).responseText;

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240});
    }


    </script>
```

Reload the web page and it produces the error:

*Table has no columns*

I don't understand why though.. I looked at other solutions and posted on Quora and the Google group for the API but to no avail.. could someone tell me whats wrong with the code??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

AJAX was changed to:

```
<?php

    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/galaxy-connect.php';

    $database = new Connection();
    $database = $database->Connect();
    $statement = $database->Prepare(" SELECT COUNT(Membership_Level_Name) AS MemTotal, Membership_Level_Name
                FROM membership AS M
                LEFT JOIN membership_levels AS L
                                ON M.`Membership_Level_Id` = L.`Membership_Level_Id`
                LEFT JOIN membership_status AS S
                                                                                                                        ON M.`MembershipStatusId` = S.MembershipStatusId
                                                                                                                        WHERE M.`MembershipStatusId` = 1
                                GROUP BY L.`Membership_Level_Name`
        ORDER BY L.`Membership_Level_Id` ");
    $statement->execute();
    $MembershipTotals = $statement->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);   


    $col1=array();
    $col1["id"]="";
    $col1["label"]="Membership Type";
    $col1["pattern"]="";
    $col1["type"]="string";

    $col2=array();
    $col2["id"]="";
    $col2["label"]="Total";
    $col2["pattern"]="";
    $col2["type"]="number";

    $cols = array($col1,$col2);

    $rows=array();

        foreach ($MembershipTotals AS $MembershipTotal) {  //foreach ($Event->TrainingTotals['ConfirmedTotal'] AS $Key => $Value) {
            $cell0["v"]=$MembershipTotal->Membership_Level_Name;
            $cell1["v"]=intval($MembershipTotal->MemTotal);

        $row0["c"]=array($cell0,$cell1);
        array_push($rows, $row0);
        }

    $data=array("cols"=>$cols,"rows"=>$rows);
    echo json_encode($data);
```

which made it a bit easier and then on the actual page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
        var jsonData = $.ajax({
            url: "/ajax/charts/membershiptotals.php",
            dataType:"json",
            async: false
        }).responseText;

    // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, {title:'Membership Bookings', width: 800, height: 500});
    }


</script>
```

Basically I had to clearly declare the columns, and the intval is to turn it into a integer, otherwise it returns the number as a string which Google doesn't like.. hope this helps anyone :)

thanks to Harish for an answer but I needed it more dynamic :-)

Answer (score 0):

this is the format of the array to be passed.

javascript:

```
var jsondata; //json data recived from php script
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsondata);
```

php:

```
$data = array(
    array('Membership Level', 'MemTotal'),
      array('Member Plus', 170),
      array('Member', 131)
    );
echo json_encode($data);
```

Your have to pass Json array not object.